# Winsound not playing sounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, winsound

I want to loop the sound with winsound but it doesn't work with

```
winsound.PlaySound(song[0], winsound.SND_ASYNC + winsound.SND_LOOP
```

and

```
winsound.PlaySound(song[0], winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC + winsound.SND_LOOP
```

The code just closes after this. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To use SND_LOOP, you have to use SND_ASYNC, and that means the sound is playing in a separate thread.  The `PlaySound` function will return immediately.  Your code is presumably going to do something else while the sound plays.  If nothing else, do `time.sleep(5)` in a loop.

Comment: well, as I said winsound.SND_ASYNC not working, but winsound.SND_FILENAME works. Also, winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_FILENAME don't work